# What causes a varistor to have low resistance when connected to a board?

Tags: circuit-protection, mov

I was inspecting the control board on a non functioning opener motor, there are no visible blown out components. No skid marks. I went to testing conductivity on the fuse component, good across there. After some googling, I saw you can test varistors via checking for infinite resistance. So I tapped all of them, one (10D431K) was reading low. I pulled it off the board and hit it with the leads of my mulitmieter, but then it read ok like the rest. I had a spare, I soldered back in and I got the same low reading from a new one.

#### Some backstory

The opener is fairly new one so I was trying to save it, or make an attempt before replacing. I had the panel replaced in my house, there was some 'creative workarounds' done by the previous owner so I don't quite know what happened when power went back to the garage, but nothing worked and it took some extra steps by the electrician to complete the job. It sounds as if ~250V (not 240V) went over the line. The lights and air compressor still function. The door opener, not so much. Verified good power to the board on the internal jumper.

#### TLDR

What causes a 10D431K MOV to show low resistance on a board, but infinite while not attached? What else should I be testing? Why is it the only one that gives me a reading when the rest show nothing? Down/upstream capacitor?

Note: I'm a curious amateur at best Have soldering iron/multimeter, will travel.

Edit - judging by the comments, I am further out of my depth than I realize. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Ummm... because there's something on the *board* with low resistance???

Comment: Why did you "hit it with the leads"? What leads?

Answer (score 0):

The board is causing the difference in the measurements.  More precisely, other components on the board that are connected to the MOV.

The MOV only reacts to high voltage.  Since the board is powered off when you are measuring things, it can't be the MOV itself.

If you don't have a circuit diagram (or can't trace the circuit yourself) then you can't tell if that low resistance reading means something is broken.

Since the MOV reads as an open circuit off the board, it is probably OK.

I can't tell you what might be wrong with the board. That would take more details than you've given - and maybe more details than is practical over the internet.  At a minimum you'd need a diagram of the circuit board - either from the manufacturer or traced by hand from the board.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring components in-circuit. When you do so, you don't only measure the component you want to measure, but also all the rest of the components in the circuit that are connected to the component you are trying to measure.